# Mac / OSx - Change PHP version which is call in bash

Tags: php, macos, bash

I have a problem with PHP which is call through bash command "php":

In bash:

> php -v        # PHP 5.3.17
>
> /usr/bin/php  # PHP 5.3.15

I want secondary PHP version 5.3.15 as mainly, because in this version I have correctly installed extensions etc.

How can I set **/usr/bin/php** as main -> I want when call "*php -v*" return my 5.3.15 version.

Execuse my bad English, I hope that you understand.

Thank you so much.
I have Mac OSx Lion

Comment: Is there any difference in the PHP functionality between those versions? (`5.3.15 vs 5.3.17`) Though the question is good.

Comment: Yes, I installed intl and some ICU library, which work only on 5.3.15 for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend you to install php through "Mac Ports".

You have multiple versions of php installed.

With the cli command "which" you can:

> DESCRIPTION
>        The which utility takes a list of command names and searches the path for each executable file
>        that would be run had these commands actually been invoked.

So read the man pages of the cli command "which".

DO this from your cli:

which php

and then you will see where is located your php executable. What i would recommend you is to replace your php executable for a symbolic link to your /usr/bin/php.

Comment: Yes the which return "/opt/local/bin/php". I think that I have a mess in PHP on my PC, because I used properly PHP, which was in OSX (Lion), but I needed php_intl library, so I installed this library through Mac Ports, and know I have two version of PHP and with php_intl and correctly set is /usr/bin/php version.

Comment: @frosty22 ok so just do what i told you remove the php link or file inside /opt/local/bin and then make a symbolic link called php inside /opt/local/bin pointing to /usr/bin/php and then this one will be your official php cli version and that's it.

Comment: Thanks remove file `/opt/local/bin/php` and create symlink - `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/php /opt/local/bin/php` work perfectly

Answer (score 41):

Another way without changing the original php file / link is if you edit your .bashrc file as follows (works with other commands as well):

1. Open your Terminal / Commandline and type in:

   ```
   vim ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. Then press "i" to get into edit-mode (if there shows up a problem before that, because of a swap file, then press "E" to edit the file anyway)
3. Add the following line (change the path as needed):

   ```
   alias php="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php"
   ```
4. Press "ESC" and type in ":wq"
5. If you need the php-alias to work right out of your current shell-session, then you have to use the following command (that's optional, so only if u r continuing to work in your current shell):

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```

That's it, no change in the /usr/bin folder needed, and u can export your bashrc file / settings to any other linux / bsd like system if needed without even touching your OS /usr/bin files. You can also add new aliases for different php versions, aliases like "php52", "php53", "php54", etc. for testing purposes or whatsoever.

Have fun,
ioCron

Comment: This guide worked for me, it should be included in some guide or wiki, after a XAMPP install, I just got the composer error, because MacOS default PHP was 7.1.3, and my laravel project require PHP 7.2, thanks!

Comment: THIS WORKED FOR ME! THANKS

Answer (score 24):

**OS: OSX Yosemite**
Just sort out a similar issue by `vim ~/.bash_profile`

> export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
>   export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin:$PATH

Make sure the order is correct. Put **`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`** before **`export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin:$PATH`**

/usr/local/bin contains the mac **default php**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

For brew users, you might not need php55 if you already have 54 - but regardless you should probably run these commands

```
$ brew install php54 php54-xdebug php54-mcrypt
```

you can substitute 54 with the latest number if you want. last i checked it was on 56

then based on some of the comments above you should run:

```
$ php --version
```

it will probably display:

```
PHP 5.4.24 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2014 21:32:15) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

if it does, then change your .bash_profile like some of the other commenters
my brew instance (i think its default) lives in

```
/usr/local/Cellar
/usr/local/bin
```

as things get installed using brew, they get put in Cellar and linked through the bin. but in this case we need to override the php

```
$ sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

mine kinda looks like:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/bin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/r/2.15.1/R.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/li$
export PATH
```

which means that it already has access to the /usr/local/bin - but i use the alias to specify 
by adding this line, near the bottom:

```
alias php="/usr/local/bin/php"
```

save and close the terminal window, open up another one, and it should show something like:

```
$ php --version
PHP 5.4.27 (cli) (built: Apr 24 2014 17:16:35) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

Answer (score 7):

You should look up the path and check all directories in the path for a symlink to the wrong php version.

Then you can remove that symlink and replace it with a link to the correct version.

You can also use `find` to see all instances:

```
$ sudo find / -name "php"
```

Comment: VERY HELPFUL in 2019 on Mac Catalina. THX