# how to change the php from the default folder to the php 71 folder

Tags: php, macos, terminal

[this my /usr/local/ folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpqQ6.png)

> this my php version showing`

```
PHP -v 
PHP 5.5.38 (cli) (built: Mar 30 2017 12:11:07)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.5.0, 
Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies`
```

> this is my PATH

`echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin`

> What i want to do is switch to my php72 folder so when i type php -v to show me php 7.2
>   I have searched a lot and tryed many solutions but it is not working.
>   any help would be appreciated

Comment: Check if this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13298091/2781096

Answer (score 0):

Go in the Finder and press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to turn on the display of the path at the bottom of the screen - no idea why Apple leaves this turned off (rant over).

Now navigate to `/usr/local/php5-7.2ORC....` and navigate around in there till you find the executable called `php`. Note the path at the bottom of the screen when you have that file selected. Remove the word `php` from the right end of that path, now set your PATH like this:

```
export PATH=<WHATEVER-YOU_GOT_ABOVE>:$PATH
```

In essence, you will end up doing *something like*:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5-7.20ORC.../bin:$PATH
```